# opengl c# edition: the amount of ram being used keeps increasing

Tags: c#, opengl, glfw

I have made this project so it renders a heart onto a black screen that can move. However it keeps seeming to be increasing the amount of ram it is using even when the heart isnt moving. I think this is due to it repeatedly rendering and then saving something in memory, however i do not know how to make it, in some way, unsave this thing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static OpenGlTutorial.OpenGL.GL;
using GLFW;
using OpenGlTutorial.Rendering.Display;


namespace OpenGlTutorial
{
    class TestGame : Game
    {
        uint vao;
        uint vbo;
        uint shader;
        int posCounter = 1;
        
        public static float[] xHeart = { -0.4f, 0.4f, 0.0f, -0.2f, 0.2f };
        public static float[] yHeart = { 0.0f, -0.6f, 0.2f};

        public static void keyCallback(Window window, Keys key, int scanCode, InputState state, ModifierKeys mods)
        {
            if(key == Keys.A && state == InputState.Repeat)
            {
                xHeart[0] -= 0.01f;
                xHeart[1] -= 0.01f;
                xHeart[2] -= 0.01f;
                xHeart[3] -= 0.01f;
                xHeart[4] -= 0.01f;
            }
            if (key == Keys.D && state == InputState.Repeat)
            {
                xHeart[0] += 0.01f;
                xHeart[1] += 0.01f;
                xHeart[2] += 0.01f;
                xHeart[3] += 0.01f;
                xHeart[4] += 0.01f;
            }
            if(key == Keys.W && state == InputState.Repeat)
            {
                yHeart[0] += 0.01f;
                yHeart[1] += 0.01f;
                yHeart[2] += 0.01f;
            }
            if(key == Keys.S && state == InputState.Repeat)
            {
                yHeart[0] -= 0.01f;
                yHeart[1] -= 0.01f;
                yHeart[2] -= 0.01f;
            }
        }
        public TestGame(int initialWindowHeight, int initialWindowWidth, string initialWindowTitle) : base(initialWindowHeight, initialWindowWidth, initialWindowTitle)
        {
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            
        }

        protected unsafe override void LoadContent()
        {
            
            string vertexShader = @"#version 330 core
                                    layout (location = 0) in vec2 aPosition;
                                    layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
                                    out vec4 vertexColor;
                                    
                                    void main()
                                    {
                                        vertexColor = vec4(aColor.rgb, 1.0);
                                        gl_Position = vec4(aPosition.xy, 0, 1.0);
                                    }";

            string fragmentShader = @"#version 330 core
                                        out vec4 FragColor;
                                        in vec4 vertexColor;
                                        
                                        void main()
                                        {
                                            FragColor = vertexColor;
                                        }";
            uint vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(vs, vertexShader);
            glCompileShader(vs);

            uint fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(fs, fragmentShader);
            glCompileShader(fs);

            shader = glCreateProgram();
            glAttachShader(shader, vs);
            glAttachShader(shader, fs);

            glLinkProgram(shader);

            vao = glGenVertexArray();
            vbo = glGenBuffer();
            glBindVertexArray(vao);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

            float[] vertices =
            {
                xHeart[0], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                xHeart[1], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[2], yHeart[1], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                
                xHeart[0], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                xHeart[3], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[3], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  

                 xHeart[3], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                xHeart[3], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[2], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  

                xHeart[1], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                xHeart[4], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[4], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  

                xHeart[4], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                xHeart[4], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[2], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  

             
            };
            fixed (float* v = &vertices[0])
            {
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * vertices.Length, v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            }
            glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

            glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            glBindVertexArray(0);


        }
        protected override void Update()
        {
            
        }

        protected unsafe override void Render()
        {
            glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


            glUseProgram(shader);
            if (posCounter % 100 == 0)
            {
                vao = glGenVertexArray();
                vbo = glGenBuffer();
                glBindVertexArray(vao);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

                float[] vertices =
                {
                xHeart[0], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                xHeart[1], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[2], yHeart[1], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
                
                xHeart[0], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[3], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f,
                xHeart[3], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 

                 xHeart[3], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f,
                xHeart[3], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,
                xHeart[2], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 

                xHeart[1], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
                xHeart[4], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f,
                xHeart[4], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 

                xHeart[4], yHeart[2], 1f, 0f, 0f,
                xHeart[4], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,
                xHeart[2], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f, 
            };
                fixed (float* v = &vertices[0])
                {
                    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * vertices.Length, v, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                }
                glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

                glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5 * sizeof(float), (void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
                glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
                glBindVertexArray(0);
                posCounter = 0;
            } 
            glBindVertexArray(vao);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 15);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
            glBindVertexArray(0);
            Glfw.SwapBuffers(DisplayManager.Window);
            posCounter++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `vao = glGenVertexArray();` and `vbo = glGenBuffer();` in `void Render()`

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new Vertex Array Object and Vertex Buffer Object, when you just want to update the buffer object's data store. Just use [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml) to update the buffer data:

```cs
protected unsafe override void Render()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    if (posCounter % 100 == 0)
    {
        float[] vertices =
        {
            xHeart[0], yHeart[0], 1f, 0f, 0f,  
            // [...]
        };

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
        fixed (float* v = &vertices[0])
        {
            glBufferSubData(
                GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(float) * vertices.Length, v);
        }
        posCounter = 0;
    } 

    glUseProgram(shader);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 15);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    Glfw.SwapBuffers(DisplayManager.Window);
    posCounter++;
}
```